# Recover file that was overwritten with python

Tags: python

I have accidentally overwritten a file called file.pkl. The variable data was None and now the file has zero bytes.

Can I somehow restore the original content of the file?

The Python process is still running in a jupyter notebook.

I use Ubuntu.

Code which I used to overwrite the file:

```
with open('file.pkl', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: If you have stored the file content in some variable in the jupyter yes, otherwise it is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the contents of the file in memory to recreate it than no. And it is no longer a python question. You need to check your filesystem and disktype to see if you can get it back. I would shutdown the drive ASAP and try to recover it with external tools.

If you did read the contents to a variable than yes that should not be an issue.